# Extracting array values from formula to reuse it in altered formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

again need you assistance

I have a range of data filled with counted values for one month. Then I sort range AK descending and get 10 first values.

```
For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand)
        Range("AF" & i + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _
                   ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
  Next i
```

Next I copy the range to AL and AM and want to apply countifs formula for only first Brands but with the same other values. Completely stack. Simply

```
Range("AL2:AL8").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz2)) & _
    ",H:H,""Headphones"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

does not work by some reason. Is there any ways through arrays or substitute? Or should I extract strings from formulas?

Comment: Assign your formula to a string, and then check the string in immediate window before using it.  Rtrim returns a string, so not sure if that is needed, or converting back to numeric?

Comment: Thought about it, but it didn’t work on the first try. Will make another attempt.

Comment: Now trying Replace but gets Type 13 error `Range("AG2:AG8").Formula = Replace(cellFormula, CStr(Month(Mesyaz3)), CStr(Month(Mesyaz3)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solution was stupidly simple. Hope, it is gonna help someone.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AH2:AH8").Replace What:=RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)), Replacement:=RTrim(Month(Mesyaz1)), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Comment: basically I wanted to use the top ten bran values as an array but it was easier to change a part of formula